# Grails URLMapping with embedded variable Not Found

Tags: rest, grails, url-mapping

I have a URLMapping.groovy file that holds the following structure:

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
        "/someThing" (resources: "someThingApi", includes: ["index", "show", "create", "update", "delete"]) {
            "/nestedThing/$type?" (controller: "someThingApi", action: [GET: "showNestedThing"])
        }
}
```

And when I call the REST interface as such it works fine (showNestedThing function is called): GET /someThing/{id}/nestedThing, however when I try and call GET /someThing/{id}/nestedThing/{type} I get the following reply:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1445247531624,
  "status": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "message": "No message available",
  "path": "/someThing/1/nestedThing/someType"
}
```

Instead of it calling the function and me being able to get the someType by doing params.type as expected. If I check my grails url mappings (grails url-mappings-report) `/someThing/${someThingId}/nestedThing/null?` shows instead of the expected `/someThing/${someThingId}/nestedThing/${type}?`.

Using Grails 3.0.9.

Answer (score 1):

While not ideal and not answering my original question there is a workaround possible for my problem in the form of removing the nested URLMapping and adding it specific later in the URLMapping file:

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
        "/someThing" (resources: "someThingApi", includes: ["index", "show", "create", "update", "delete"]) {
            "/nestedThing/$type?" (controller: "someThingApi", action: [GET: "showNestedThing"])
        }
}
```

Becomes:

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
        "/someThing" (resources: "someThingApi", includes: ["index", "show", "create", "update", "delete"])
        "/something/${someThingApiId}/nestedThing/${nestedThingApiId}?" (controller: "someThingApi", action: [GET: "showNestedThing"])
    }
}
```

This fixes the problem for now, but doesn't answer the question why my original nested code wasn't working.